# Using ether.js with metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am considering using [ether.js](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/index.html) instead of web3js. One of the factors I am considering is the integration with metamask.

Is there any support in ether.js to use metamask as wallet? 
If there isn't, will a simple decorator pattern wrapping around browserside-metamask-injected-web3js do the trick?

One more question, is ether.js stable and well supported?

Answer (score 4):

Actually the answer can be found in the ethers.js doc.

Ethers.js supports web3 providers, so to get it to work metamask on browser is quite simple.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  var web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider, ethers.providers.networks.ropsten);
  web3Provider.getBalance("..some address.."). then(function(balance) {
    var etherString = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
    console.log("Balance: " + etherString);
  });
}
```